# In Universal Hashing- probability of poor performance is small and is the same for any set of keys of the same size

Tags: proof-techniques, probability-theory, hash, hash-tables, hashing

I was going through the text Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. where I came across the following claim:

> Universal Hashing uses randomization.For the example of a compiler's symbol table, we find that the programmer's choice of identifiers cannot now cause consistently poor hashing performance.
>
> Poor performance occurs only when the compiler chooses a random hash function that causes the set of identifiers to hash poorly, but the probability of this situation occurring is **small** and is the **same for any set of identifiers of the same size**.

Now let us assume that in the general case( not specifically the compiler example) we have a "Universal class of Hash function" as $\mathscr{H}$ and the set of keys be $K$.

As the situation described ,the poor performance occurs if for a randomly chosen hash function $h\in\mathscr{H}$ the hash function causes collision for each $\binom{|K|}{2}$ pair of keys. Intuitively that the probability of this happening is quite "small" is justifiable. But that the probability is **same for all sets K of size n and independent of the actual keys in it** was not received by me in an intuitive manner and I thought of finding the probability of such an event and satisfy myself.

From the definition of universal class of hash function we know that,

For each pair of distinct keys $k,l$ the number of functions $h\in \mathscr{H}$ , such that $h(k)=h(l)$ is atmost $\frac{|H|}{m}$ where $m$ is the number of slots in the hash table .i.e. for the set $A=\{h \in \mathscr{H} : h(k)=h(l)\}$ ,

$$|A|\leqslant|\mathscr{H}|/m \tag 1$$

Now from the above we need to find the number of hash functions which causes collision for all pair of keys.

Let $A_{x,y} \subseteq \mathscr{H},$ for $\forall x,y \in K$ such that the keys $x\neq y$, $A_{x,y}$ contains those hash function $h$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$.

Now

$$\lambda = \left| \bigcap\limits_{(x,y\in K)\land (x\neq y)} A_{x,y} \right| (say) \tag 2$$

We know that,

$$\left| \bigcup\limits_{(x,y\in K)\land (x\neq y)} A_{x,y} \right| \leq |\mathscr{H}|\tag 3$$

So the required probability which I am asking for becomes,

$$p=\frac{\lambda}{|\mathscr{H}|}\tag 4$$

Now how to combine $(1), (3)$ to get a bound for $(2)$ and hence get a bound for $(4)$.

---

I thought of an alternative approach though.

Let $h$ be the hash function chosen at random during the start of the execution of our algorithm. Suppose $X_{x,y}$ be the indicator random variable defined as :

$$X_{x,y} = \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\text{if $h(x)=h(y)$ }\\
       0&\quad\text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Where the randomness is due to the random selection of $h$ and not on the keys. Now by the definition of Universal Hashing, $Pr\{h(x)=h(y)\}\leq \frac{1}{m}$ where $h$ is randomly chosen hash function for keys $x,y$. So $E(X_{x,y})=Pr\{h(x)=h(y)\}\leq \frac{1}{m}$

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the total number of collisions.

$$X=\sum_{(x,y\in K)\land (x\neq y)} X_{x,y}$$

Taking expectations on both sides,

$$E[X]=E\left[ \sum_{(x,y\in K)\land (x\neq y)} X_{x,y}\right]$$

$$\implies E[X]=\sum_{(x,y\in K)\land (x\neq y)} E[X_{x,y}]= \binom{n}{2} E[X_{x,y}]\leq \binom{n}{2}.\frac{1}{m}$$

Now using Markov's Inequality we have,

$$Pr \left\{ X\geq\binom{n}{2}\right\} \leq \frac{E[X]}{\binom{n}{2}} $$

$$\leq \frac{\binom{n}{2}.\frac{1}{m}}{\binom{n}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{m}$$

$$\therefore p=Pr \left\{ X\geq\binom{n}{2}\right\} \leq\frac{1}{m} \quad\text{(independent of the actual keys)}$$

Please help me out with the first approach or is my second approach legit?